# Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.common.RandomWrapper

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mahout, netbeans-8

I am building a Software using Java 8 with Hadoop and Mahout 0.10.0 with some custom changes in the code of Mahout Library.

I am using Maven to manage dependencies.
Other dependencies are being handled by the maven like hadoop common and hdfs and yarn.
I am having trouble while runtime of the task which internally uses `RandomWrapperClass`.

The Following Error occurs to every map operation:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.common.RandomWrapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass
```

I have added the dependency in the `POM.xml` too.
I can import the Class appropriately in the code section.
I have added the dependency in the repository of maven.
I have a appropriate jar loaded into the repository and also it contains the `RandomWrapper.class`

Answer (score 0):

While this happens in runtime, for me it looks like a missing library in Mahount classpath.

Put jar that contains changed `RandomWrapper` class to Mahout classpath libs.